# Need help with hot water temp in kitchen sink

Tags: plumbing

I have hot water to the rest of the house, but not to my faucet in the kitchen sink. Water pressure is good for both, but the hot water comes out luke warm. No leaks, water heater running fine, no blockages anywhere. Please help. I'm stumped. Oh, it's been like this over the last 10 hours.

Comment: It's a lever-style faucet, right? Unless you've got some kind of recirculating pump problem (probably not), the problem is your faucet, right? How about a picture or three so that people can figure out what kind of faucet it is and provide diagnostics from there?

Comment: Do you have a temperature mixing/anti-scalding valve there(usually in newer/recent plumbing)?

Comment: @crip659 I hope not in the kitchen. They've fitted them in work, fixed to a comfortable hand-washing temperature, and you can't get sensible washing up temperature without resorting to adding some boiling water from the dispenser

Comment: @ChrisH  A failed valve would match OP's problem and be a simple choice.

Comment: @crip659 What valve? The hot water valve? Sorry, not a plumber, so some of the jargon is not familiar with me.

Comment: That's why you need to provide pics of the faucet from above and below the counter so people can help identify parts and indicate what may have failed.

Comment: @crip659 so would a simple mixer valve failure, without the need for an anti-scald valve in the wrong place. But in case there is such a valve, pictures of anything on the pipework under the sink would be helpful